# Знаки препинания

Tags: пунктуация

"Дерется(,)значит(,) мужик" — правильно ли тут расставлены знаки препинания?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первая часть этого сложного бессоюзного предложения указывает на условие совершения действия, названного во второй части. Поэтому ставим тире.

Далее. Что такое ЗНАЧИТ? Это союз, соединяет предложения или части сложного предложения  (в том числе в составе двойного союза «**если... значит**» или «**раз... значит**»). Сближаясь по значению с вводными словами «следовательно», «таким образом», союз «значит» отделяется запятой (реже тире) от последующей части предложения.
В нашем примере мы для верности можем восстановить контекст. Получится что-то типа: "Если (раз) кто-то дерется, значит, он мужик". Имеем двойной союз "если (раз)... значит".

Выходит, правильные знаки препинания такие: "*Дерется - значит, мужик*".

Answer (score 0):

Если слово **значит** находится между частями **бессоюзного** сложного предложения, то оно также выделяется ***запятыми***: Прозвенел звонок, значит, урок кончился; Не уберегли ребёнка, значит, пеняйте на самого себя. (http://www.ngebooks.com/book_27869_chapter_32_x_x_x.html)